# Two Units, one Class, TSocket and second Unit has to change object color on Form

Tags: class, sockets, delphi, events

I have to prepare an individual unit to communicate with another system by TCP/IP.

I created two units: `Unit1` with a `TForm`, and `Unit2` with communications.

**Unit1:**

```
uses ..., Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Circle1: TCircle;
...

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Communication: TCommunication; 

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Communication.ClientSocket1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Communication := TCommunication.Create;
end;
```

Unit2:

```
uses SysUtils, ScktComp;

type
  TCommunication = class(TObject)
    ClientSocket1 : TClientSocket;
    procedure ClientOnRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure ClientOnConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

procedure TCommunication.ClientOnConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  // Change circle to Green
end;

procedure TCommunication.ClientOnRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  s : String;
begin
  s := ClientSocket1.Socket.ReceiveText;
end;

constructor TCommunication.Create;
begin
  ClientSocket1 := TClientSocket.Create(nil);
  with ClientSocket1 do
  begin
    Address      := '127.0.0.1';
    Port         := 4545;
    OnConnect    := ClientOnConnect;
    OnRead       := ClientOnRead;
  end;
end;
```

I have no idea how I can change the `Circle`'s color, or how to create an event inside `Unit1` to let `OnConnect` and `OnRead` take new actions.

`OnRead` is very important to create some steps on the TForm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have `TCommunication` expose its own events that the `TForm` can assign event handlers to.  Just as `TCommunication` is assigning handlers to `TClientSocket`'s events.  For example:

Unit1:

```pascal
uses ..., Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Circle1: TCircle;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CommunicationOnConnect(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CommunicationOnRead();
  ...
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Communication: TCommunication; 

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Communication.Connect;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Communication := TCommunication.Create;
  Communication.OnConnect := CommunicationOnConnect;
  Communication.OnRead := CommunicationOnRead;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Communication.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.CommunicationOnConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Change circle to Green
end;

procedure TForm1.CommunicationOnRead(Sender: TObject;
  const Data: String);
begin
  // do something with Data...
end;

end.
```

Unit2:

```pascal
uses Classes, SysUtils, ScktComp;

type
  TCommunicationReadEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const Data: string) of object;

  TCommunication = class(TObject)
    ClientSocket1 : TClientSocket;
    procedure ClientOnRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure ClientOnConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Connect;
    procedure Disconnect;
    OnConnect: TNotifyEvent;
    OnRead: TCommunicationReadEvent;
  end;

implementation

procedure TCommunication.ClientOnConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  if Assigned(OnConnect) then OnConnect(Self);
end;

procedure TCommunication.ClientOnRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  s : String;
begin
  s := Socket.ReceiveText;
  if Assigned(OnRead) then OnRead(Self, s);
end;

constructor TCommunication.Create;
begin
  ClientSocket1 := TClientSocket.Create(nil);
  with ClientSocket1 do
  begin
    Address      := '127.0.0.1';
    Port         := 4545;
    OnConnect    := ClientOnConnect;
    OnRead       := ClientOnRead;
  end;
end;


procedure TCommunication.Connect;
begin
  ClientSocket1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TCommunication.Disconnect;
begin
  ClientSocket1.Active := False;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It's working. But is there a way to treat OnRead inside Unit2 and show it in a MEMO in Unit1 for example? I will have to reuse this code.

Comment: "*is there a way to treat OnRead inside Unit2 and show it in a MEMO in Unit1*" - I already showed you how to do that. `TCommunication.ClientOnRead()` can manipulate `s` as needed before calling `OnRead(Self, s)`, and then you can place your desired Memo code inside of `TForm1.CommunicationOnRead()` to display the `Data` as needed.